# Android emulator crash on Mac osx 10.7 lion, causing kernel panic

Tags: android

I am using Android emulator with an intel x86 based image for version 2.3 and developing on a Mac 10.7 lion system.
I have also installed intel hardware execution manager due to which the emulator runs at faster speed than normal. However while using the emulator it crashes randomly causing a kernel panic.
This happens quite frequently. Any clues to how I may get over this !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug with the android emulator on a mac system.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19099